# How to get resolved value of promise then export using module.exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, module.exports

I have this Promise snippet,

```
    let myPromise = new Promise(async function(resolve, reject){

    const defaultConfig = {
            s3: {
                region: process.env.ENV_S3_REGION,
                accessKeyId: await juice.string('S3.ACCESS_KEY_ID', juice.MANDATORY),
                secretAccessKey: process.env.ENV_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
            },
            uploadConfig: { 
                bucket: process.env.ENV_UPLOAD_BUCKET
            }
}
   resolve(defaultConfig);
}
```

And I'd like to module.export the defaultConfig object. So I did this at the end of the code,

```
myPromise.then(res => module.exports = res)
```

But when calling in on other file, it can't get the value, it gives me undefined.
But if I console.log the res like, this I can output the value.

```
myPromise.then(res => console.log(res))
```

Comment: Relevant: [Is it an anti-pattern to use async/await inside of a new Promise() constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229)

Comment: The export happens before the promise resolves and you can't make it wait. Export the promise instead.

Comment: @Quentin, I see. That would be a hassle in my current code.

Comment: If I export the promise itself, then in the importing file I'd refactor the code, and move everything inside the .then so I can get the value right?